# Deleting protected hidden .git directory with WinAPI

Tags: c++, windows, file, winapi, filesystems

#### The goal

I have a directory with files in it. Also this directory includes `.git` folder that is protected from deleting by user (and some files in it too).

The goal is to read files in this directory and then delete it with `WinAPI`.

#### Manual deleting

- Deleting in console with `rm -r .git` throws an exception:

  ```
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied
  ```
- Deleting in console with `rm -r -force .git` works fine.

#### WinAPI deleting

I'm opening some file in this directory like this:

```cpp
HANDLE file = CreateFile(path,
                GENERIC_ALL,    // DELETE, WRITE and READ
                FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_WRITE | FILE_SHARE_READ,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE, // some flags
                NULL);
```

and it fails with error `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

Also, I tried to run the program with administrative rights, but it didn't work.

##### So here is the question:

- How can I **force** open this file and modify or delete it?

###### PS

- I know that I can use `std::filesystem` and it works, but WinAPI is required here.
- I didn't check the `DeleteFile()` function for deleting this file, but still I have to read the file's data before deletion, so `CreateFile()` is required (and `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE` for deleting works fine, so I don't need the `DeleteFile()` function).

###### Additional questions

- How does this 'file protection' work in Windows? (it's simpler in Linux)
- Are my 'share mode' settings (`dwShareMode param`) correct?

Comment: *use std::filesystem and it works* - internal it anyway use winapi, you can try enable `SE_BACKUP_PRIVILEGE` and `SE_RESTORE_PRIVILEGE` in token (if thay exist here) and use  `FILE_FLAG_DELETE_ON_CLOSE|FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS` in flags. also instead `GetLastError()` call `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` , not use `GENERIC_ALL` but for instance `FILE_GENERIC_READ|DELETE`. bile not have read only attributes ? this is file, not folder ?

Comment: if you try open directory, not file - you got `STATUS_FILE_IS_A_DIRECTORY` (this `RtlGetLastNtStatus()` return) but `GetLastError()` convert this code to `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`, despite this is nothing common this access denied

Comment: If `std::filesystem` works then `RemoveDirectory` should work, or use `IFileOperation` if directory is not empty. Are you using `rm` command in Administrator mode? I think `-force` just deletes without asking for confirmation, it's not related to folder protection (maybe). Can you manually delete that folder in Explorer (using mouse clicks) without being blocked for Admin access? Also post some code and show `GetLastError()`

Comment: Sorry, I will only check your suggestions on Monday... But thanks for the help ^^

Comment: Yeah, issue was about readonly files and after many tries I'm just.. manually setting read only attribute off  and that's all.
You can't delete readonly file in windows, privileges don't matter here... Thank you all, also advice about `RtlGetLastNtStatus` was very helpfull.